# Syntax Error "elif" unexpected expecting then

Tags: shell-script

i am posting a new question to bugfix for my code.

```
    if [ -f /etc/centos-release ]; then
        OS="CentOs"
        VERFULL=$(sed 's/^.*release //;s/ (Fin.*$//' /etc/centos-release)
        VER=${VERFULL:0:1} # return 6 or 7
    elif [ -f /etc/lsb-release ]; then
        OS=$(grep DISTRIB_ID /etc/lsb-release | sed 's/^.*=//')
        VER=$(grep DISTRIB_RELEASE /etc/lsb-release | sed 's/^.*=//')
    elif [ -f /etc/os-release ]; then
        OS=$(grep -w ID /etc/os-release | sed 's/^.*=//')
        VER=$(grep VERSION_ID /etc/os-release | sed 's/^.*"\(.*\)"/\1/')
     else
        OS=$(uname -s)
        VER=$(uname -r)
    fi
```

Here `elif [ -f /etc/lsb-release ]; then` code shows the error.

Answer (score 4):

If the shell reports that error on the 5th line of the script you posted, there must be some invisible error with the `then` on the first line.

You could view your script with `cat -A` to see if there are accidental ALT-space characters or other non-printable characters on the line. `cat -A` will show line-feed characters as `$` at the end of each line, control characters with the `^` prefix, and nonprintable characters with the 8th bit set with the `M-` prefix. For example, TAB characters will show up as `^I`.

The `cat -A` output can look a bit messy, but it's a great way to ensure there aren't any non-printable characters where they should not be.

Comment: likely a carriage return (`^M`) preventing the shell from recognizing the `then` at end of line

Comment: That is one of the possibilities, yes; another common nuisance is Alt-space. `cat -A` should catch them all.

Comment: Tried it.  Still the same issue comes.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your file by running the following command:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this type of problem. The solution for me was to run dos2unix on the file. Everything was fine afterward.

Answer (score 0):

That script snippet runs fine for me.  As @telecoM notes, is likely some odd characters within your script.

```
$ cat -A x1
#!/bin/bash$
    if [ -f /etc/centos-release ]; then$
        OS="CentOs"$
        VERFULL=$(sed 's/^.*release //;s/ (Fin.*$//' /etc/centos-release)$
        VER=${VERFULL:0:1} # return 6 or 7$
    elif [ -f /etc/lsb-release ]; then$
        OS=$(grep DISTRIB_ID /etc/lsb-release | sed 's/^.*=//')$
        VER=$(grep DISTRIB_RELEASE /etc/lsb-release | sed 's/^.*=//')$
    elif [ -f /etc/os-release ]; then$
        OS=$(grep -w ID /etc/os-release | sed 's/^.*=//')$
        VER=$(grep VERSION_ID /etc/os-release | sed 's/^.*"\(.*\)"/\1/')$
     else$
        OS=$(uname -s)$
        VER=$(uname -r)$
    fi$
$ ./x1
$
```

Comment: I exactly used the same code in new . it results the same issue